# How to access .Net performance counters in compact framework?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have an application created by using .Net Compact Framework 3.5.

In this application I want to log information about various counters e.g. GC time ( how much time GC took to perform ) , memory status and so on .

In the full .Net version we have `PerformanceCounter` class, but what is equivalent in the .Net compact framework or how can I find these performance counters?

An example with small code snippet will be great...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an equivalent. But you can install the PerformanceCounter from:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15267